# getting JSON from DBI:Pg selectall_arrayref

Tags: json, perl, dictionary, dbi

I have an array

```
my @cols = ("accountid", "balance");
```

and a dataset

```
my $rowsref=$dbh->selectall_arrayref($_[0]);
foreach my $row (@$rowsref) {
    print join(", ", map {defined $_ ? $_ : "(null)"} @$row), "\n";
}
```

which prints `"1, 150"`.

I would like to get a JSON output like `[{"accountid": 1, "balance": 150},{..}]`.

I have the JSON module loaded, but unsure how to merge `@cols` with each `$row`.

Comment: By the way, that's not valid JSON. JSON has double quotes around Object keys, as well as around all String values.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I was just typing it as an example but I will fix for the sake of purity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** added explanation of column name transaction in 2nd example
**edit:** Fixed for your requirement of a single JSON encoding of the whole resultset.
**edit:** forgot `keys` in cols mapping code in 2nd example.
**edit:** typo'd hashref everywhere to arrayref. :-

Firstly, use [selectall_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm#selectall_hashref) instead, so that it already contains the key names.
Then use one of the JSON encoding modules to encode each row.

(making the same assumptions as your code....)

**Using the list-of-hashrefs from selectall_hashref() as-is:**

```
use JSON::XS;
use 5.10.0;
my $rowsref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($_[0]);
print JSON::XS::encode_json($rowsref),"\n";
```

**Performing translation on colnames from selectall_hashref():**

If the column names from the database aren't the same as your column names, then you'll need a mapping:

```
use JSON::XS;
use 5.10.0;
my $trans = { account => 'accountid', amount => 'balance' };
my $rowsref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($_[0]);
my $output = [];
for my $row (@$rowsref) {
    push @$output, {
        map { 
            my $colname = exists($trans->{$_}) ? $trans->{$_} : $_;
            my $value   = $row->{$_};
            $colname => $value;
        } keys %$row                   
    });
}
print JSON::XS::encode_json($output),"\n";
```

For each `$row` above of the resultset, `keys %$row` gives back the column names in the row as returned from the database.

The `map` operation takes each of those column names and producues 2 scalar values; (1) `$colname` is either the original database column name or (if it's found in the `$trans` hashref) a 'translation' of the column name; (2) `$value` is the value returned by the database for this column name in this particular `$row`. `$colname => $value` returns both the `$colname` and `$value` from the map as a 'flattened' pair of scalar values. That means that the `map` operation returns a list of scalar values twice as long as the original list of column names returned by `keys %$row`.

Finally, the `push @$output, { ... }` creates an anonymous hash reference from that list of scalar values in `key,value,key,value,...` order and adds it to the end of the $output array reference.

**Blind translation from `selectall_arrayref()`**

If (for some reason) you have a pathological aversion to querying hashrefs from your database, I guess you could do:

```
use 5.10.0;    
my @cols = ("accountid", "balance");
my $rowsref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($_[0]);
my $output = [];
for my $row (@$rowsref) {
    my %row = map { $cols[$_] => $row->[$_] } (0 .. $#cols);
    push @$output, \%row; 
}
print JSON::XS::encode_json($output),"\n";
```

That assumes there are only two columns coming back from the query, though.

**"Defined or" operator:**

By the way... assuming a late enough perl, you can replace this sort of thing:

```
defined $_ ? $_ : "(null)"
```

with this:

```
$_ // "(null)"
```

Your code editor (e.g: Vim) might not syntax highlight it correctly if it's not up to date with perl. (e.g: it might treat it as an `m//` construct).

Comment: using emacs, no aversion to hashref if it works. experimenting with an alpha database but I will certainly try this tonight and report. thanks.

Comment: Your first example gives an error, which could be db related, but the second example works perfectly! thanks. could you add a quick explanation of what the map function does in this case? would be good for future reference.

Comment: Not sure what the error could be for the 1st example. Works for me. I'll add some explanation for the 2nd example.

Comment: 1st one might be because of the database I'm using. For example, it doesn't yet support prepared statements so it may not respond correctly to the hashref. I wouldn't worry about it. I'm using perl 5.10.1 for what it matters. The 2nd example was exactly what I was after though and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Note that PostgreSQL can also generate [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html). If it is an option for you then Perl JSON module is redundant.

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks, but I'm actually using the PostgreSQL driver to interface with a different DB. Otherwise, this would be the obvious way to go.